# Angular start ngFor index from 1

Tags: angular

Is it possible to start ngFor index from 1 instead of 0?

```
let data of datas;let i=index+1
```

didn't work.

Comment: why you want the same may i know ? or please elaborate your question bit more

Comment: You can't use + operator in ngFor but you can use it inside the body with `i`. see @Taylor response below.

Comment: [What about this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72910957/148271)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
 *ngFor="let item of items | slice:1; let i = index;
```

[SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

Comment: @ BBaysinger Who is Rad?

Comment: This is removing data from end. Is there any way to slice from both end?

Comment: For now I am using *ngIf to achieve it(Is it recommended one?), or I can use custom pipe. But, why 'slice' pipe is working unexpected for me?

Comment: slice pipe is returning a subset of the initial "items" set. This means that **it is not** the index starting from 0, but the items list starting from the second element in the set.

Answer (score 29):

There are 2 possible answers to the question, depending on what was actually being asked.

If the intent is to skip the first element of the array, then the answers involving *slice* are in the right direction.

**However, if the intent is to simply shift the index** while still iterating over **all** of the array, then slice is NOT the correct approach, as it will skip the 0th element in the array, thereby outputting only `n-1` items from an array of length `n`.

@Taylor gave a real-world example of when the index might need to be shifted for display purposes, such as when outputting a list where the first entry should read 1, not 0.

Here's another similar example:

```
<li *ngFor="let book of books; let i = index">
    {{ i + 1 }}.  {{ book.title }}
</li>
```

which would produce output like:

1. Sample Book Title
2. Another book title

...

Comment: Imo that's a bad example. You use an ordered list in HTML and use the index to show the number of the item in the list .. CSS gives you that by default :)

Comment: Of course, there are easier/better ways to make a numbered list.  However, this example was intentionally chosen for its clarity, and to maintain focus on the question raised (which is not about numbered lists).

Comment: Best one. Easy and Quick

Comment: this is the best answer because 1. skipping the 1st item in the list when reading in json from a network request only equals incomplete data, 2. the complaint that ol is not the correct html assumes I have full control over that (not always true). 

just needed a quick way to number questions from 1 and up.

Answer (score 24):

That's not possible, but you could use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to skip the first element:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of list.slice(1)">{{ item }}</li>
```

The [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) is also an option if you prefer that syntax:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | slice:1">{{ item }}</li>
```

> **Description**
>
> All behavior is based on the expected behavior of the JavaScript API `Array.prototype.slice()` and `String.prototype.slice()`.
>
> When operating on an `Array`, the returned `Array` is always a copy even when all the elements are being returned.

If you also need the index to match, just add the number of elements you skipped to it:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of list.slice(1); let i = index">{{ i + 1 }} {{ item }}</li>
```

Or:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | slice:1; let i = index">{{ i + 1 }} {{ item }}</li>
```

Anyway, if you need to put too much logic in the template to make this work for your use case, then you should probably move that logic to the controller and just build another array with the exact elements and data that you need or cache the sliced array to avoid creating a new one if the data hasn't changed.

Answer (score 15):

```
  <li *ngFor="let info of data; let i = index">
    {{i + 1}} {{info.title}}
  </li>
```

Answer (score 11):

This works fine for me. With single quote

```
*ngFor="let data of datas; let i = 'index+1'";
```

In this way I don't remove any data from the array datas and at the same time the index starts from 1 and it ends to datas length.

Comment: This should be the top answer! It actually works without slicing off any of the array!

Answer (score 4):

You can't at least for now, it seems the team behind angular 2 is trying to keep ngFor really simple, there's a [similar issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10611) opened on Angular 2 repo about doing multiple assigning of the index and the answer was:

> syntax has to be simple for tools to support it.

Answer (score 1):

We can approach it like the below for custom tags/default tags:

```
 <custom-tag *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [text]="Item + getIndex(i)"></custom-tag>
```

In Javascript:

```
function getIndex(i) {return Number(i + 1).toString();}
```

Comment: I used to approach this with {{ i + 1 }} and it worked fine for a while.  Just recently started getting errors about i not being a numeric, and so this approach is working for me now

Answer (score 0):

I am using **let i = index** in *ngFor class. As it is start from 0th element, so I am using here **{{i+1}} instead of {{i}}, it will skip the 0th element in the array**. It works fine for me...

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let key of ques; let i = index">
  <ion-text>{{i+1}}) {{key.question}}</ion-text>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it around a div then use `*ngIf="i != selectedIndex"` like this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of yourArray; let i = index">
     <div *ngIf="i != selectedIndex"> {{ item }} </div>
 </div>
```

where `selectedIndex` is the item index you want to remove