# Angular 2: *ngfor not letting me declare an index

Tags: angular

I am trying to declare an index in *ngFor but I am getting a type error and it is saying

> Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined with the ERROR on *ngFor

```
<div class="text" *ngFor="let item of blogs; let i = index | async | filter : 'feat' : true">
```

If I take out let i = index it works fine, but I want to use the index, so I can apply css classes to the elements. Looking at documentation, this is how you are supposed to do it.

Comment: your question is not clear, and can you please explain actually what you are trying to achieve, so that i can give you a proper code for the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular start ngFor index from 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057119/angular-start-ngfor-index-from-1)

Comment: You can't do any operations in the index, if you want to declare the index it has to be something like this: `<div class="text" *ngFor="let item of blogs; let i = index;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
<div class="text" *ngFor="let item of blogs | async | filter : 'feat' : true; let i = index">
```

Answer (score 1):

`index` is maintained by `ngFor` and exported as `index`. All you can do is to define a name of a template variable you want to access that index with. You can't apply pipes or calculations to that assignment.