# ngFor index plus 1 or incresed count by one

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

How to get in angular 2 the index but increased by 1:

```
<li *ngFor="let mPrepTasks of project.upcomingMeetingsPrepTask; let i= index; let count = i+ 1;">
   <p>Index {{count}}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70709356/14590375)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
<li *ngFor="let mPrepTasks of project.upcomingMeetingsPrepTask; let i= index;">
   <p>Index {{i + 1}}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create arbitrary template variables. Inside `*ngFor` you can only declare variables that are provided by the `*ngFor` directive.

Either do what @FilipLauc said or do the calculation in the component class instead.

Answer (score 0):

#### THIS WORKS

Use single quote. It doesn't remove any data from the array items and at the same time the index starts from 1 and it ends to items.length.

```
*ngFor="let item of items; let i = 'index+1'";
```