# Looping using ngFor and skip nth element

Tags: angular, ngfor

I was wondering if there is a way in angular2 to loop through an array or a list using `*ngFor` and skip the first or nth element

Comment: @aloisdg It is not really a duplicate, as it is asking for skipping 1st element. I am asking for nth element in general. The answers are also way different.

Comment: Indeed. My close is retracted. (I will delete this comment too)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
  <div *ngIf="i != n">{{i}} is not n</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I skip each Nth element, like each 3d or each 2d?

Comment: Sure, you can use the modulo operator `%` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators like `*ngIf="i % 3 != 0"`. `i` will still count them. You can also use a pipe that returns an array that doesn't contain these elements, then `i` will match the number of visible elements, not the number of source elements.

Answer (score 12):

I just learned from another issue, you can do it with Slice pipe

```
 *ngFor="let item of items | slice:1;
```

where **1**  is your *n*th element

https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

see also:
[Angular start ngFor index from 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057119/angular-start-ngfor-index-from-1)

Comment: *ngFor="let item of items | slice:1 (without the comma)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipe in the loop like this:

html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let element of object | values"> {{element}} </li>
</ul>
```

In the pipe element you can define everything that you want to control.
For example
in pipe component (values.pipe.ts):

```
@Pipe({ name: 'values' })
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args: string[]): any {
    let values = []
    for (let key in value) {
      values.push(value[key])
    }
    return values
  }
}
```