# Remove options from select angular 4

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I need help in a scenario and scenario is on a page i have 4 select input and each input have their on source like 4 copies of items from master in object.

eg

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="onChange($event,i)" class="select-bx" placeholder="Select Security Question" [(ngModel)]="objQuestListModel[i].selQuestionId">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let items of objQuestList[i]" value="{{items.QuestionId}}">{{items.QuestionText}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

so i want to remove all selected items from each dropdown but keep the selected items for selected dropdown.

for eg in dropdown 1 if i selected A option then from all rest dropdown it should be removed 
in dropdown 2 if i selected option B then it should be removed from dropdown 1.
i am using angular 4 with cordova.

Please help me .

Regards
Anil Kumar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372560/looping-using-ngfor-and-skip-nth-element

Answer (score 0):

I do not know ionic so i will use angular syntax.

In your component typescript file you should do something like this:

```
private selectedOptions:number[] = [];

private onChangeSelectBox(event:any){
    let value:number = event.target.value;
    if(this.selectedOptions.indexOf(value) == -1){
        this.selectedOptions.push(value);
    }
}


private showOption(optionId:number):boolean{
    return this.selectedOptions.indexOf(optionId) == -1;
}
```

And in your html file:

```
<select (change)="onChangeSelectBox($event)">
      <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="yourItemsCollection">
         <option *ngIf="showOption(item.id)" value="{{item.id}}">
            {{item.name}}
         </option>
      </template>
<select>
```

Comment: "let-" is only supported on ng-template elements.