# How to skip the first and the last item in a *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a list of items. The first row is a kind of header. The last row is a kind of footer. My header and footer need a specific treatment, so I don't want to display through this loop.

json:

```
{
  "items": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

My code right now:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item in items">
 <li>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Output is:

```
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Output should be:

```
<ul>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the shiny slice pipe:

> Creates a new `Array` or `String` containing a subset (slice) of the elements.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | slice:1:items.length-1">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

- [Try it Online!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4h5pu?file=src/app/SlicePipeList.component.ts)
- [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

Answer (score 9):

You can use a good old index:

> index: number: The index of the current item in the iterable.

```
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
        <li *ngIf="i != 0 && i != items.length-1">{{item}}</li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

- [local-variables](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)
- [Looping using ngFor and skip nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42372560/1248177)

Answer (score 9):

You can use local variables first and last:

> - first: boolean: True when the item is the first item in the iterable.
> - last: boolean: True when the item is the last item in the iterable.

```
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; first as isFirst; last as isLast">
        <li *ngIf="!isFirst && !isLast">{{item}}</li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

- [local-variables](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)
- [Try it Online!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhmjsz)