# Angular 5 ngFor let i=index+3

Tags: angular5, angular2-forms, ngfor, angular-reactive-forms

Is there a way to set index to start not from 0 ? Or modify it to add each time some number?

I have an array of 8.
I need to divide it in two 4 groups but still leave it in one collection , for it also a nested reactive form and the order of the items has a meaning.

So , I need only to divide it in two groups and nest it inside an expantion-panel of the material-design.

So far so good, but..

The second group starts, naturaly the count from 0, because it is an iteration of new group from his point of view.
I could've maybe add trackBy or modify idx by recognition of the data in the items type but it is not the elegant way.

So the question is , how to enable the index to start customly from the number I would define. I would like this loop to start from 4 position..

```js
updateEntity(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
  //this.idx - should start from 4 for the second part of mat-expansion-panel
  this.children.at(this.idx).patchValue({
    id: ...
  });
}
```

```html
In the Parent

<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      Buyer
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div *ngFor="let item of Entity | slice:0:4; let idx=index">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <entity-search [children]="form.controls.Entity" [child]="item" [idx]="idx">
          </entity-search>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      Seller
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div *ngFor="let item of isfEntity | slice:4:8; let idx=index">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <entity-search [children]="form.controls.Entity" [child]="item" [idx]="idx">
          </entity-search>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>



In Entity Search:



<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" placeholder="{{child.placeholder}}" required matInput formControlName="entityName" aria-label="Number" [formControl]="searchEntity" [matAutocomplete]="autoEntity">
  <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
  <mat-autocomplete #autoEntity="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="updateEntity($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of searchEntityResult" [value]="item">
      {{ item.id + " " + item.entityName + " " + item.entitySecName }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057119/angular-start-ngfor-index-from-1

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to simply shift the index by +3 every time you use it in the second array. I found no other solution. e.g.

```
....
<entity-search [children]="form.controls.Entity" [child]="item" [idx]="idx + 3">
</entity-search>
...
```

Related to [this post](http://Simple%20(kind%20of%20dirty)%20solution%20would%20be%20to%20simply%20shift%20the%20index%20by%20+3%20every%20time%20you%20use%20it%20in%20the%20second%20array.%20I%20found%20no%20other%20solution.%20%20%20%20%20%20....%20%20%20%20%20%3Centity-search%20[children]=%22form.controls.Entity%22%20[child]=%22item%22%20[idx]=%22idx%20+%203%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/entity-search%3E%20%20%20%20%20...%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057119/angular-start-ngfor-index-from-1)

Answer (score 0):

At the end that's what I've done

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of Entity | slice:4:8 ; let idx2=index">
  <p [hidden]="true">{{ idx2 + 4 }}</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <entity-search [children]="form.controls.isfEntity" [child]="item" [idx]="idx2">
      </entity-search>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```