# Angular: increment value inside html with typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor, string-interpolation

In Angular I have a variable inside typescript, initialized with value 0. Now In my `.ts` file I want to increment it with `*ngFor` . I tried it in this way, but increment is not happening. (though loop is running perfectly)

**a.page.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of sn">
  {{myNumber++}}
</div>
```

**a.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stock-modal-one',
  templateUrl: './a.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.page.scss'],
})
export class AModalOnePage implements OnInit {

  myNumber = 0;

  sn = ['a', 'wefwef', 'qwqw', 'qw', 'qw'];

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Why you want to increment value inside HTML?

Comment: @Rajan Lets say, its a serial number. (that i count by loop, not coming from any database)

Comment: @Frost https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lu2dva?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Go to this link Is it working for you?

Comment: I'd add that number to `sn` in my code: `sn = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((n, i) => ({ n, i: i + 1000 }));` and use `{{item.n}}` and `{{item.i}}` in my template. That way you have total control over the index, and the template is cleaner.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda well i changed sn .  sn = ['a', 'wefwef', 'qwqw', 'qw', 'qw'];
Ur example is good . but this array means my ng for will go 5 time, and I need to start counting with ngfor from a specific number . so if i start at 100, loop will run 5 times, and i want to get 101 102 103 104 105

Comment: @ChrisG please see the comment above, i wanted something like this

Comment: Ok, but doesn't my comment already tell you how to implement this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rgeeyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @ChrisG yes now it is perfect. thanks

Comment: @Frost https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lu2dva?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts , I would recommend to use angular pipe, Here in this case its very useful

Comment: @GaurangDhorda sure I will look into this also

Comment: @Frost When you use pipe, the logic inside pipe is same you can repeat in any of your component. For better structure of your app you can go with pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is index instead. Try this code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of sn; let i = index">
  {{i}}
</div>
```

Comment: can I initialize i to a certain value? (like i = 1000  , so it will be 1001, 1002, ...)

Comment: only if you start the array from the 1000th index. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057119/angular-start-ngfor-index-from-1) question.

Comment: You can simply use `{{ i + 101 }}` in the template...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display serial number you can use index for it.

```js
<div *ngFor="let item of sn; let i = index">
  {{i}}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer , but will this work if i want i to start from 1000? (like 1000, 1001, 1002...)